# How to use possibly undefined key as index

Tags: typescript

I try to use keys from an object to index a new type, but those keys are possibly undefined so I get TypeScript error:

```
Type '"field"' cannot be used to index type '{ key1: { field: string; }; key2: {}; }[T]'.(2536)
```

```
const obj = {
 key1: {
  field: {
   foo: 1,
   bar: 2,
 },
 key2: {}
}

type Foo<T extends keyof (typeof obj)> = {
  [key in keyof (typeof obj)[T]['field']]: string
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What should a valid value be, `{ hello: "world" }`?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, i realized i made a mistake in my example, i just fixed it with edit.
So to awnser your question, a valid value for `Foo<'key1'>` would be `{foo: string, bar: string}`
And for `Foo<'key2'>` it would be undefined

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you need to modify your code so that it checks whether the 'field' property is actually present in the object before trying to use it. You can use conditional types, which lets you perform a kind of "if-then" check within your types.

```
const obj = {
  key1: {
    field: 'hello'
  },
  key2: {}
}

// Utility type to extract keys from 'field' if it exists, or return never otherwise
type FieldKeys<T> = T extends { field: infer F } ? keyof F : never;

// Type Foo that only uses keys from T where 'field' is defined
type Foo<T extends keyof typeof obj> = {
  [P in FieldKeys<(typeof obj)[T]>]: string;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
That's close to what I want but that doesn't solve it.
I want to create a type which keys are created from keys in `obj.T.field`, and because it can be undefined I got the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the awnser to my will thanks to @skerdi-velo who suggested to use conditional type.

```
type Foo<T extends keyof (typeof obj)> = 
(typeof obj)[T] extends { field: infer F } ? {
  [key in keyof F]: string
} : undefined

const t1: Foo<'key1'>; // Of type {foo: 1, bar: 2}
const t2: Foo<'key2'>; // Of type undefined
```